# SCCM Database on the SQL Server instance shared with other applications

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, architecture

My company uses SCCM with a dedicated SQL Server instance that is using version 2016.

I noticed that this VM is completely idle for most of the time. I barely see any CPU activity, wait statistics since a startup are almost equal to 0. In this situation, I wanted to move SCCM related databases to the SQL instance with version 2019 that would be shared with other applications that are not very active. It would allow me to reduce SQL licencing cost.

During the migration, we have encounter two issues.

Firstly process failed with an error

```
ERROR: Site server does not have admin rights on remote sql server machine '*Destination SQL instance*'
```

We passed that through by adding the primary site server to the local admin group on the new SQL instance. It was a little bit expected, because that prerequisite was mentioned on different websites.

But after that process failed again with an error:

```
Failed to get sql service account, Server:<>,instance:<>

Error: Unsupported Sql service account
```

At this point, we rolled back the change.
At the Destination server, we use 'Managed Service Account' as a SQL Service account so I suspect that was a problem. Could you please advise if that could be the case or it is something else?

I was expecting that we will simply re-point SCCM app to the new server and it will be communicating with a SQL server as most of the other applications. Looking at the error messages that we got during the installation it seems that is not the case. SCCM is trying (at least during the installation) interact with instance and VM level objects. In this situation, I wonder if that is safe to share its databases with other applications.

Could you please advise if anyone is using SCCM with its database on the SQL instance shared with other applications? Is there any risk associated with such an approach (I mean specific to SCCM, not related to consolidation problems in general)?

Answer (score 0):

I am having this same exact issue!
We added the SQL Service account as an Admin on the Primary Site server and then we were able to connect and run the Site Setup Wizard to point SCCM to the new shared SQL server.

Comment: After encountering the problems that I described I get back to some digging about the whole idea of putting SCCM on the shared instance and I found that article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/core/understand/product-and-licensing-faq 
This indicates that a standard SQL license is 'included' for the configuration manager as long as the instance is dedicated only to that porpoise... So we have aborted the idea of moving that anywhere.